# Port Security for Access Point in Cisco Switch

Tags: security, switch-statement, port

I have a Cisco SG300 Switch. I want to configure Port Security with only one MAC address allowed. But I have a Access Point in my network. So what should I do ? Can I configure Port Security on that port where AP has been connected.

I have not tried yet. Asking for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely , you can set up Port Security on the port that your Access Point (AP) is connected to. It's all about managing the amount of MAC addresses allowed on that port.

Here's the thing though - if you're gonna set the MAC limit to one , that might be a problem. Why? Because each device connected to your AP has its own MAC address. So, if you cap the MAC addresses to one, you'd effectively be limiting the number of devices that could connect through your AP to just one device. That's probably not what you're shooting for, right?

So, here's my advice. Set the MAC limit to a number that makes sense for your network. If you're expecting like, say , 50 devices to connect via your AP, make the MAC limit 50. Or give yourself some wiggle room and make it 60.

If you're dead set on locking it down to one MAC address , that should be the MAC address of your AP. But remember, this means you're saying "No Vacancy" to all other devices trying to connect via that AP.

In a nutshell , Port Security is a kickass way to help secure your network by limiting the number of devices that can connect to a switch port, but it requires a bit of juggling when it comes to APs. The trick is setting the right MAC limit for your needs.

Comment: Ok...got your point. Thanks for the help.